# How to get Image Meta Data (picture taken date) with ImageResizer and C#

Tags: c#, exif, imageresizer

I've got a byte[] of data that is actually an image file. I want to get the picture taken date (if it's in the meta data).

I use ImageResizer.  Any way to use that tool to get this info?  What is the next best way? I've scoured the internet and can't find anything built into .net /c#

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data. [System.Drawing.Image.PropertyItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx) can read this data, for example:

```
// Create an Image object. 
Image image = new Bitmap(@"c:\FakePhoto.jpg");

// Get the PropertyItems property from image.
PropertyItem[] propItems = image.PropertyItems;
```

MSDN has more details in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

System.Drawing has primitive metadata support. We've been working for the last year on getting MetadataExtractor ported to .NET, and the result can be found here:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

and on NuGet

`Install-Package MetadataExtractor -Pre`

The scope of metadata parsing is quite large, and didn't fit well within ImageResizer.